# Bitmap is lost the quality of image when getting from the storage of android

Tags: android, android-bitmap, image-quality

I am facing issue with Bitmap image quality when getting a image file from internal storage and show on imageView. How to show image file with original quality using bitmap.

Here is my code

```
 fun renderPdf(renderer: PdfRenderer, pagesBitmap: MutableList<Bitmap>, dir: File) {
    try {
        for (i in 0 until PAGE_COUNT) {
            val document: PDDocument = PDDocument.load(dir)
            val pdfRenderer = PDFRenderer(document)
            val bim = pdfRenderer.renderImage(i, 3.5f, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888!!)
            pagesBitmap.add(bim!!)
            document.close()
            // Save the render result to an image
            val path: String =
                Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString() + "/.AOF/aof_$i.jpg"
            val renderFile = File(path)
            val fileOut = FileOutputStream(renderFile)
            pagesBitmap[i].compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, fileOut)
            fileOut.close()
        }

        ivForm.pagesBitmap = pagesBitmapFiles
        ivForm.displayPDFDocument()
        renderer.close()
    } catch (e: IOException) {
        Log.e("PdfBox-Android-Sample", "Exception thrown while rendering file", e)
    } finally {
        callDocumentType()
    }
}
```

Comment: @blackapps sir kindly check

Comment: `facing issue with Bitmap image quality when getting a image file from internal storage and show on imageView.` ?? there is no such things in the code you posted.

Comment: i have removed the image please tell me sir how to resolve this issue bitmap loss quality of my image file.

Comment: You said in the title you are getting an image from storage, but your code suggests that you are getting a PDF file from storage and render it into an image.

Comment: @RickyMo exactly im doing rendering the pdf file and the it convert in to a image and image qualify is lost the very bad text cant read.

Comment: Then your question is written incorrectly and misleading. You are not getting an image file and it magically lost quality. You are getting a PDF file and rendering it to an image with low quality. So the problem is the rendering quality.

Comment: is 100 the highest compression or the highest quality? If it is the highest compression when you're doomed because JPEG is lossy. Consider saving as PNG or use a different compression.

Comment: yes its rendering quality how to fix it sir please tell me I am stuck around 3 days

Comment: is there any sample code of it ?

Comment: According to the document of [renderImage(int pageIndex,float scale,ImageType imageType)](https://pdfbox.apache.org/docs/2.0.3/javadocs/org/apache/pdfbox/rendering/PDFRenderer.html#renderImage(int,%20float,%20org.apache.pdfbox.rendering.ImageType)), you can adjust the scale, 1 corresponds to 72 DPI. You are using 3.5 which corresponds to 252 DPI. You may try to increase the number.

Comment: @RickyMo so do you think should i do change the value 3.5f to 252DPI?

Comment: You can use [renderImageWithDPI(int pageIndex, float dpi, ImageType imageType)](https://pdfbox.apache.org/docs/2.0.3/javadocs/org/apache/pdfbox/rendering/PDFRenderer.html#renderImageWithDPI(int,%20float,%20org.apache.pdfbox.rendering.ImageType)) if you want to specify DPI directly. Both will work. You just need to play around with different values to get your desire quality. Just try using different number. Trying doesn't harm. No need to seek my confirmation. I would never know what you want exactly.

Comment: exactly i tried many times and set the different values but result was same original image is pretty good and its readable but when I convert into bitmap or rendering with DPI so its decrease the quality and image text unable to read

Comment: Please try to save it as PNG and see if it looks good. While 252 dpi sounds like a weird number, this is a rather good resolution. I also think you didn't understand my comment: JPEG being "lossy" means that high compression = shitty image but small file size. Low compression = nice image but big file size. Try 10, 50, 90 instead of 100 and see what happens re: file size / beauty. Also please share your PDF.